# FileNotFoundException in a function while another function is using the file with no issues

Tags: android, file, exception, kotlin

I am getting this error
`Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/media/external/images/media/119 (No such file or directory)`

on the variable `takenImageUri` While calling this function ([using this library](https://github.com/hkk595/Resizer?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=6155)):

```
refBigImage.putFile(
            Uri.fromFile(
                Resizer(this.context)
                    .setTargetLength(80)
                    .setQuality(100)
                    .setOutputFormat("PNG")
                    .setOutputFilename(randomName + "Small")
                    .setOutputDirPath(storagePath)
                    .setSourceImage(File(takenImageUri))
                    .resizedFile
            )
)
```

The way I get that uri id from a previous fragment where the photo was taken. This is the function in action that creates it.

```
private fun takePhoto() {
        val photoResult = fotoapparat?.takePicture()

        fun getImageUri(inContext: Context, inImage: Bitmap): Uri {

            val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()

            inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes)

            val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.contentResolver, inImage, "Title", null)

            return Uri.parse(path)
        }


        photoResult
            ?.toBitmap()
            ?.whenAvailable { bitmapPhoto ->
                val uriImage = getImageUri(this.context!!, bitmapPhoto!!.bitmap)

                val action =
                    CameraPreviewFragmentDirections.actionCameraPreviewFragmentToApproveImageFragment(uriImage.toString())
                findNavController(camera_nav_host_fragment).navigate(action)
            }
    }
```

This file is an image, and prior to calling this function, I am loading the image into an ImageView and it shows perfectly fine, so I know the path is correct. Why is it gibving me this error if this file exists there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting this error Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/media/external/images/media/119 (No such file or directory)

That is because it is not a file. You are passing a string representation of a `content` `Uri` to something that needs a filesystem path. That `Uri` is a value that you (or something) obtained from the `MediaStore`.

Comment: Ok I see, can you please point me the right direction? I'm not sure how to make the conversion

Comment: @Tsabary: That library does not appear to support reading in an image from a `Uri`. Short of modifying the library, there is no simple fix.

Comment: @CommonWare ok thanks for clarifying that definitely saves me trouble of messing around. i've added the code from the previous fragment where I believe there is a file being generated. Maybe I am just passing the wrong thing over to the next fragment? Is there something I can do with the data from the previous fragment to make this work?

Comment: @Tsabary: If your objective is to put this image somewhere that the user has access to it, then you are better off finding a better library, or forking that one and making changes to it. If that is not your objective, get rid of `getImageUri()` and write your `Bitmap` to internal storage (`getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()` on `Context`), and you get a `File` that you can use with that library.